# What's the difference between the "me" and the "I" used in the quote below?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, context

I read the next words (part of a bigger sentence, coming from musical lyrics):

> But my parents, they lived through the Blitz years, and **me**, **I** was sent to a farm.

Why are **me** and **I** used, instead of:

> And **I**, **I** was sent to a farm.

By the way, when I type the last sentence I'm not corrected by the grammar and spelling control program. Of course, the program says I'm wrong when writing two times **me**:

It just doesn't feel good to say:

"and me, me was sent to a farm."

Is it maybe because of the context in which these words are used? Or is there maybe some rule which says you have to use **me** and **I** in the way I described? I find it kind of strange because in Dutch we have also **me** ("mij") and **I** ("ik"), but used differently. We don't say the quote above with **me** and **I**, but two times **ik**. We do say, though, "give it to me!" (for example): "geef het aan **mij**". And there are more of these different usages of the two.

Comment: @Lawrence I don't think this is a dupe of those. Reason being those don't involve left dislocations.

Comment: **COMPARE:** “What happened to John?” “Him? He was sent to a farm.” Or even “Me, I stayed home.”

Comment: @Araucaria Although I agree that the form used in this question is different, the choice between the words *me* and *I* comes down to the preceding sentence or chunk that "And" links to. E.g. compare: (1) They sent *him* to the city. And *me*, .... (2) *He* went to the city. And *I*, .... The questions I linked to explain why "me" goes with #1 and "I" goes with #2.

Comment: @Lawrence I don't think so:. Could easily be: "John was sent to prison. And me, I was sent to the farm"

Comment: @Araucaria The principle is similar, though I concede that the form is different. Do you have something in mind by way of an answer to the current question? If so, let me know and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: In ordinary prose (as distinct from song lyrics) I think it would be more usual to say "As for me, I was sent...". Another possibility (after listing what happened to other people) would be "And I? I was sent..."

Comment: @Lawrence Not quite juicy enough to pull me away from my work right now ... :)

Comment: More context is needed, as justification for either phrasing may be made (see Lawrence's comment, above).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the 'you and me' question. As a sentence introduction, it is a different phenomenon.

Comment: In "I/me, I" in your example, the first "I/me" is not a subject, while the second "I" is a subject.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: But ***(what happened to)*** my parents, they lived through the Blitz years, and ***(what happened to)*** me, I was sent to a farm.

Comment: I give a +1 because It seems pretty plausible, though I don't think the additions apply because the living through the Blitz years doesn't **happen** to someone, neither does being sent to a farm **happens** to someone. Can you answer the question (I'm not thát good in English): **What happened to you?**  with: **I lived through the Blitz years.**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**But my parents, they lived through the Blitz years, and *me, I* was sent to a farm.**

The sentence above contains **the use of an indirect object pronoun as an appositive**. Me, you, it, him, her, us, you, them,

Apposition is very common in English, and it is used to emphasize the next word. It is usually used in speech or in recounting a story (narration) to a reader. I am only giving spoken examples, as I am too lazy to look for others or dream them up.

An [appositive](http://dailygrammar.com/emails/Lesson%20126.htm) is a word or group of words that identifies or renames the noun or pronoun that it follows.

Here are some other examples:

"Him, he took the gun and shot her", said John.

"Them, they wandered through my class like sleepwalkers", the professor complained.

"You, you are the one who broke my glasses", the man shouted at me.

"No, it, that stupid dog peed on my living-room rug last night, not the cat", the lady whined.

Please note: with you and it, the  pronoun is repeated because the object or subject pronouns are the same thing: you and it.

Their is also a deictic function going on, here but that's not a grammatical feature. It's more stylistics....

'

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I disagree with the accepted answer.

This cannot be an appositive because appositives are in the same case as the noun they replace.

So, an appositive would be: "I, The Z, will go home." It would not be: "Me, the Z, will go home."

What is actually going on in this sentence is the omission of some words, possibly "as for" but many things could work here.

> But [as for] my parents, they lived through the Blitz years, and [as for] me, I was sent to a farm.

So, there are four clauses here, two independent clauses and two dependent clauses.

They are "I was sent to a farm" and "they lived through the Blitz" because that's how you use those pronouns. When they are the subject, they are in those forms.

It is "[as for] me" rather than "[as for] I" because that is how you use the pronoun after a preposition.

Another reason you know this is not an appositive but a dependent clause is that, in the appositive, either there are no commas or the second noun or phrase is surrounded by commas.

> An appositive is a word or group of words that identifies or renames the noun or pronoun that it follows. It is set off by commas unless closely tied to the word that it identifies or renames.
>
> [Daily Grammar](https://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-126-Appositives.htm)

In the original text, however, we neither see an absence of commas nor the second noun/phrase being surrounded by commas. We see what we would expect in dependent clauses, a comma separating the dependent clause from the independent one.

Sometimes, the first clause is made into a question as well. For example:

> Q: What happened to John? A: [To] him? He was sent to a farm.

Could even be:

> A: [You are asking about] him? He was sent to a farm.

Your example from Dutch is probably some form of an appositive because the *I* stays in the same case. However, English does not seem to have common practice of using an appositive only to repeat the same word (in the same case).